# Is ArrayList a data structure?

Tags: arrays, arraylist, data-structures

I have heard two students arguing online in a social network site whether ArrayList is a data structure, however, they did not come up with conclusion.

Student B started the topic with statement "ArrayList is not a data structure", the following is points he made

- ArrayList is a java implementation of LinkedList in array. Standard one (The C one) ArrayList cannot be regarded as a data structure
- ArrayList is a java implementation of dynamic array
- Data structure is a concept of regulating how the data to be stored or accessed, ArrayList is not a data structure because it is an implementation of the data structure named "dynamic array"

There are few points Student A (Supporting ArrayList is a data structure) made.
He starts with giving definition of data structure (Student A provides reference link 1,2,3).

- ArrayList is a data structure because it is classified as dynamic array
- Meaning of data structure is very broad, implementation of one of data structures can still be classified as data structure

Their argument ends with one of them stop commenting on this topic.

I would personally like to know whether "ArrayList" can be classified as Data Structure or not. Why or why not?

Under what rules, a "Data Structure" should not be classified as Data Structure?

Ref link 1: [Definition of Data Structure by NIST](https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/datastructur.html) 
Ref link 2: [Definition of Data Structure here by Encyclopædia Britannica](http://www.britannica.com/technology/data-structure) 
Ref link 3: [List of data structure by NIST](https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads//)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed a data structure in fact the very links you refer clearly state it. Any organization of data qualifies in my opinion. In computer science we have common abstract concepts more commonly studied but there is no restriction on how you organize or structure data for efficiency or use.